# How can I call a processor only 1 time when dealing with many flow files?

Tags: apache-nifi

I've got a rather large flow that runs just once a day.

At the end of the flow is processing group that deals with logging all issues detected to a database. So 0-n calls are made to the database which is all based on if errors are detected on each flow file.

The problem that I am trying to solve is I need to send 1 email and only 1 email if any errors exist in the flow files.

MergeContent will not suffice as only the errors exist at the end are available. So I would not have all of the flows needed to try to control the flow with that.

I'm looking for suggestions on how can I limit the call to the processor only 1 time when there are >1 flow files with errors?

Comment: store all flowfile statuses somewhere (file or database) and trigger reporting/email subflow once a day.

Comment: @daggett I'm not sure what you mena by reporting flow but I'm guessing I could use the ExecuteSQL with a 24hr interval to check and see if any entries exist for the day and if so send the email, or is the reporting you mention some processor I should know about?

Comment: right - just trigger by schedule a flow that will send an email with errors (if there are any).